# ArrayAdapter throws error on notifyDataSetChanged if the List<array> has less than 7 items

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm new to android development. I have an arrayadapter that is updated on the click of a button. There are 4 array lists: adModelsList, adModelsList_SJ, adModelsList_SD and adModelsList_MJ. The view updates if the array list has more than 7 items. When the list has less than 7 items it crashes. What am I doing wrong??

Here is the arrayadapter:

```
public class AdAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    private List<AdModels> adModelsList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AdAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<AdModels> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.resource = resource;
        adModelsList = objects;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        sjBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sjBtn);
        sdBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sdBtn);
        mjBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mjBtn);

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
                holder.overskrift = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adoverskrift);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

           holder.overskrift.setText(adModelsList.get(position).getOverskrift());

                sjBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        adModelsList = adModelsList_SJ;
                        ((AdAdapter) lvAds.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

                sdBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        adModelsList = adModelsList_SD;
                        ((AdAdapter) lvAds.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

                mjBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            adModelsList = adModelsList_MJ;
                        ((AdAdapter) lvAds.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

                lvAds.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        AdModels admodel = adModelsList.get(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("adInfo", new Gson().toJson(admodel));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });


            return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        private TextView overskrift;
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
  Process: dk.forsoegsperson.fp, PID: 12603
  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
  at dk.forsoegsperson.fp.MainActivity$AdAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:261)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1366)
  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1662)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Edit** Simplified the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since I was introducing a new array every time I had to clear the array, add the new list, notify the adapterarray and set the adapter. This did the trick.

Here is the code:

```
 xxBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    adModelsList = adModelsList_SD;
                    ((AdAdapter) lvAds.getAdapter()).clear();
                    ((AdAdapter) lvAds.getAdapter()).addAll(adModelsList);
                    ((AdAdapter) lvAds.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    lvAds.setAdapter(AdAdapter.this);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong behaviour because of this:

```
 if (cor_count > 0) {
     convertView = null;
 }
 else {
    cor_count = adModelsList.size();
 }
```

after updating the adapter's adModelsList, the cor_count variable won't be updated correctly to the new size

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added that to try to empty the recycler. If I don't have that if statement the app crashes if adModelslist.size becomes less than 7 on the onClick (which is the amount of rows visible in the view upon getview). Also cor_count does get the correct amount of variables upon update.